# How to limit list items display in ListView

Tags: android

I am getting XML data from url and displaying using a custom list adapter in a `ListView`.

I need to display only 10 items in `ListView`.

How i can do this?

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Please, show the code you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only put 10 items in the adapter. Or override `getCount()` and return `10`.

Comment: I managed to set 10 objects to the adapter, solved issue.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The adapter you're using with the ListView only displays the item you put in it.
Just put in your adapter 10 items, or whatever other number you want, and it will display only that items.